# Minimizing a function and finding the optimal point

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, approximation, maxima-minima, approximation-theory

We have a function
$$
f(x)=\frac{(1-q^x)\times q^{(2-x)}}{x^2}
$$
The task is to find the point where the function is minimum. I have an assumption that  $q$ is a value in the range $(0,1)$.

I am trying to find the closed-form solution for $x_{min}$, the point of minimum.

My attempt is as follows:

> Taking log followed by derivative w.r.t $x$  and equating it to zero gives,
>
> $-\frac{q^{x} \times log (q)}{1-q^x}-log (q)-\frac{2}{x}=0$
>
> $\implies\frac{1+q^x}{1-q^x} \times log(q)=-\frac{2}{x}$

How to simplify further is where I am facing problem? **I am  specially interested in the case when $q$ is closer to 1.** I tried the following approximation :

> $\frac{1+q^x}{1-q^x}=\frac{2-px}{px},$ where $p=1-q$. This lead to $x_{min}=\frac{2}{log(1/q)}$.
>   But, in fact, I would like to improve this using a better approximation. Can someone give me any tips on how to proceed ? What better approximations can I use?

Comment: Do you really need to have a closed form solution for $x_{min}$?

Comment: @sammygerbil, I am interested in it. A closed form approximate solution is useful. I understand that I can solve the equation using other iterative methods. But, since I am ok with an approximate solution, I am trying to see if a closed form solution can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{(1-q^x)\times q^{(2-x)}}{x^2}\implies f'(x)=\frac{q^{2-x} \left(2 q^x-x \log (q)-2\right)}{x^3}$$ So, we need to solve for $x$
$$2 q^x-x \log (q)-2=0$$ the solution of which being
$$x_*=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)+2}{\log (q)}\approx -\frac{1.59362}{\log (q)}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Now
$$f''(x)=\frac{q^{2-x} \left(-6 q^x+x \log (q) (x \log (q)+4)+6\right)}{x^4}$$ and then
$$f''(x_*)=-\frac{2 q^2 \left(W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)+1\right) \log
   ^4(q)}{W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)
   \left(W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)+2\right)^3}$$ which is positive if $0 \leq q \leq 1$; so $x_*$ corresponds to a minimum.

Now
$$f(x_*)=-\frac{q^2 \log ^2(q)}{W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)
   \left(W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)+2\right)}\approx 1.54414\, q^2 \log ^2(q)$$